# error in the jdbc for EE while working for SE mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar for JDBC in a desktop application with JAVASE 7 (which is working fine) but for JAVASE 6 (with the same code as in JAVASE 7 app) its not working. neither I can see any exception in console nor any debugging prints that I made. what can be wrong?

heres my project folder http://open-pages.com/temp.zip

Comment: Are you using anything specific to Java 7 in the Java 6 application?  That may cause issues.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: i cant even know. no errorloging.java nor console printouts are working. why ?      2. it doesnt returns true in the entry.userAuthDAO.verifyUserPass(userName, password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your issue involves java 6 vs. Java 7. Nothing in your code is using Coin syntax as far as I read. The issue is java desktop app vs. Web application. Is the JDBC driver included in the war file? (in the library folder) I usually configure database connections in context. xml and obtain a dataSource using InitialContext.

Just write a simple test jsp or Servlet to connect to your database and display some query results. You can just print anything exceptions right to the web page to make it easy for testing. I'm not sure why the exceptions weren't getting written to your log file (check for the most recent files written to the log folder of your server)

```
<%-- mysqlTest.jsp :For testing mysql connection and database query syntax --%>
<html><body>
<h2 align="center">SQL Test for mySQL JDBC Driver</h2>
<%
java.sql.Connection con = null;
try {
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con=java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "abc");
    if(con!=null) {
        String query="select userName, password from users";
        java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
        java.sql.ResultSet r=stmt.executeQuery();
        while(r.next()){
            out.print(r.getString(1));
            out.println("<br>");
        }
        r.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
    else
        out.println("<strong>The Database connection is null.  DriverManager could not return a valid connection.</strong>");        
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        out.println("Cannot load driver<br>" +e.toString());
    }
    catch(java.sql.SQLException e){
        out.println(e);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        out.println(e);
    }
    finally {
        if(con!=null)
            con.close();
    }
%></body></html>
```

Comment: solved. i had to use Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");      is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but in deployment it's better to use a Connection Pool configured through context. xml.  Opening a db connection with every request is inefficient.